# I'm not able to use nodeSelector attribute in mixed worker node environment on ICP 2.1GA

Tags: ibm-cloud-private

I am on ICP 2.1 GA and have a mixed worker node (Intel and Z worker nodes) environment. I have tried

```
nodeSelector: { nodetype: z }
```

with the nodetype label set on the nodes but ICP is not honoring the nodeSelector attribute in the deployment JSON.

Is there anything more to be done in ICP than defining nodesSelector attribute in deployment JSON and adding corresponding labels used in the nodeSelector attribute to the nodes?

Answer (score 0):

The node must have a label attached to it and for it to be selected for, the pod config file needs to have the nodeSelector attribute defined inside it with a matching label and value.

For example, the node name is '10.0.0.1' and label 'nodetype=z'.

```
kubectl label nodes 10.0.0.1 nodetype=z
```

And add a nodeSelector section to the deployment.json.

```
{
  "apiVersion": "extensions/v1beta1",
  "kind": "Deployment",
  "metadata": {
    "name": "deployment",
    "labels": {
      "app": "nginx"
    }
  },
  "spec": {
    "replicas": 3,
    "selector": {
      "matchLabels": {
        "app": "nginx"
      }
    },
    "template": {
      "metadata": {
        "labels": {
          "app": "nginx"
        }
      },
      "spec": {
        "containers": [
          {
            "name": "nginx",
            "image": "nginx:1.7.9",
            "ports": [
              {
                "containerPort": 80
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
        "nodeSelector": {
          "nodetype": "z"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```